# After uninstalling Ubuntu, does the Ubuntu partition get added back to the Windows partition?

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows.

Now I want to uninstall Ubuntu. After I delete the Ubuntu partition using Windows disk manager, will the Ubuntu partition be added to my Windows partition?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t need your Ubuntu partition anymore, consider it being an empty (unpartitioned) space. Windows is not able to read-write data from Ubuntu partition, but you definitely can do what you want with this space (e.g. use it to extend your Windows partition.)

Answer (score 0):

BE CAREFUL.

Deleting the partition will not remove Grub. Furthermore, Grub won't be able to load Windows anymore and you'll end up with a Grub rescue prompt.

You need to repair the MBR as well.

See [this link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) for more information and proceed with caution.

Comment: thanks for your help. The reason I'm trying to uninstall ubuntu is that I'm having a acer Aspire timeline U3 laptop which has a dedicated VGA.When I'm in ubuntu ubuntu doesn't use on-board VGA but the dedicated one.So when I'm in ubuntu the laptop works nearly 2 hours.I really like working in ubuntu.Can you  help me with this?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question explaining your problem and adding the results of `lspci | grep Graphics`. There are plenty of users ready to help.